# Mathematical French: étant - does it introduce an assumption or a fact

Tags: terminology

What does the form *étant* mean in the following sentence, excerpted from an article by E. Szpilrajn:

"La fonction $f_e$ étant mesurable $(K)$, tous les ensembles de la suite $e$ et leur complémentaires appartiennent à $K$."

1. Does it mean: "$f_e$ being measurable w.r.t. $K$, all the sets of the sequence $e$ and their complements belong to $K$", implying that the measurability of $f_e$ is an established fact at this point.
2. Or does it mean: "Whenever $f_e$ is measurable w.r.t. $K$, all the sets of the sequence $e$ and their complements belong to $K$", implying a condition, whose premise might not be satisfied, i.e. $f_e$ may not always be measurable w.r.t. $K$, but if it is, all the sets of the sequence $e$ and their complements belong to $K$?

Comment: Option 1. Or "Since $f_e$ is measurable w.r.t. $K$ ..."

Comment: Any intuition I have for French suggests that _étant_ is the present participle of _être_, but I'm not native French so not certain. Thus, 1. has my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a summary of the situation. We begin by two quotes from the paper:

> **1.3 Suites d'ensembles appartenant à un $\sigma$-anneau.** Soient: $K$ une classe de sous-ensembles d'un espace $X$ et $e=\left\{E_n\right\}$ une suite de sous-ensembles de $X$. Les ensembles $C_n^0$ et $C_n^2$ étant ouverts dans $C$ (voir 1.1(iii)) et l'ensemble $f_e(X)$ étant contenu dans $C$, il résulte de 1.2(iii) que
>
> a) La fonction $f_e$ étant mesurable $(K)$ ${}^{1)}$, tous les ensembles de la suite $e$ et leurs complémentaires appartiennent à $K$.
>
> ${}^{1)}$ au sens de 0.4.

---

> 0.4 $K$ étant une classe de sous-ensembles d'un espace $X$ et $Y$ un espace métrique, je dis qu'une fonction $f$ définie sur $X$ est $(K)$ mesurable, lorsqu'on a $f^{-1}(G)\in K$ pour chaque sous-ensemble ouvert $G$ de $Y$. (...) Si $X\in K$, on a évidemment :
>
> (i) Pour que la fonction $f_E(x)$ soit mesurable $(K)$, il faut et il suffit qu'on ait : $E\in K$ et $X\setminus E\in K$. (...)

---

There are two options to understand *étant*, either it means **if** or it means **since**.

In *Les ensembles $C_n^0$ et $C_n^2$ étant ouverts dans $C$ (voir 1.1(iii))*, *étant* means **since** (note that 1.1(iii) states that the sets $C_n^i$ are open and closed in $C$).

In *l'ensemble $f_e(X)$ étant contenu dans $C$*, *étant* means **since** because the inclusion $f_e(X)\subseteq C$ is always true (and is obvious from the definition of $f_e$).

But, in *La fonction $f_e$ étant mesurable $(K)$*, *étant* cannot mean **since** because $f_e$ is not always measurable $(K)$. A simple case when $f_e$ is not measurable $(K)$ is given by the OP in a comment:

> Let $E$ be some non-trivial subset of $X$ and define $K:={X}$, $e=(E_n)_n$, $E_n=E$. Then $f_e=\mathbf 1_E$. According to 0.4(i), if $X∈K$, $f_E$ is $(K)$ measurable if and only if $E∈K$ and $X\setminus E∈K$, which is clearly not the case here.

Hence, the only option is that *étant* in *La fonction $f_e$ étant mesurable $(K)$* means **if**.

To conclude, *étant* is used alternatively as **since** and as **if** and it is used as **if** in the occurrence the OP mentions (hence, Option #2).

Comment: Kudos to the OP for having stuck to their guns, and apologies from me for a too cursory first reading of Szpilrajn's paper. I quickly spotted an example of *étant* meaning **since** and I deduced (falsely) that this extended to every occurrence of *étant* in the paper. Sorry again.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! :)

Comment: De rien. À dire vrai, je ne suis pas très fier d'être passé trop vite sur votre question la première fois. Merci d'avoir insisté.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, *étant* is the present participle of *être*, the French verb meaning *to be*. So hypothesis 1. is correct.

**Warning:** For all questions on the French language always be  sure to only trust people with typical French names, like  Szpilrajn or  yours truly

G. Elencwajg

Comment: Thank you. I'm not quite convinced, but peer pressure has done me in.

Comment: @EvanAad This must be the worst reason I can imagine (and a quite disappointing comment to read for those of us who tried to provide facts and arguments in support of their opinions).

Comment: @Did: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but the truth is, it still doesn't make sense to me in the context of the article. I explained myself in the comment below and, while i agree that i did not quote the piece verbatim, the fact remains that $K$ is introduced as an arbitrary family of sets and there is no reason at the point (a) to assume that $f_e$ is measurable with respect to it. The reference to 1.2(iii) doesn't justify the measurability of $f_e$, rather in tandem with the assumption of the measurability of $f_e$, it yields the consequence that $e$'s sets and their complements belong to $K$.

Comment: @Did: I have to disagree with you and here's a simple counter-example. Let $E$ be some non-trivial subset of $X$ and define $K:=\{X\}$, $E_i:=E$. Then $f_e$ is just $f_E=\mathbb{1}_E$. According to 0.4(i), if $X\in K$, $f_E$ is $(K)$ measurable iff $E\in K$ and $X\backslash E\in K$, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: @EvanAad I reread the paper. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, I'd go for (1). Étant is the present participle of être, so 'being' is a good translation. Not only that, but a common phrase is 'étant donné que', which has the same meaning as 'given that', so it seems like the meaning would carry over to this sentence.

Not a native French speaker though, so may be best to wait until one comes along and answers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna sound like a snotty, ignorant jerk, but i have to disagree with everyone, even though i'm not a native French speaker (obviously...), whereas at least one of the respondents is and even though i have the highest regard to all the respondents, especially to Davide Giraudo, who has answered some of my mathematical questions in the past.

Option #1 just doesn't make sense in the context of the article, imo. Here's a larger excerpt surrounding the sentence in question. Please let me know if you agree with me.

---

Soient: $K$ une classe de sous-ensembles d'un espace $X$ et $e=\left\{E_n\right\}$ une suite de sous-ensembles de $X$. Les ensembles $C_n^0$ et $C_n^2$ étant ouverts dans $C$ et l'ensemble $f_e(X)$ étant contenu dans $C$, il résulte que

a) La fonction $f_e$ étant mesurable $(K)$, tous les ensembles de la suite $e$ et leur complémentaires appartiennent à $K$.

Nous allons démontrer qu'on a d'autre part:

b) $K$ étant un $\sigma$-anneau et $e$ étant une suite d'ensembles appartenant avec leur complémentaires à $K$, la fonction $f_e$ est mesurable $(K)$.

---

In my opinion the "étant"-s used in the first paragraph are indeed meant to establish facts, but the "étant"-s used in (a) and (b) introduce the legal conditional that can sometimes be found in legal texts (again, i'm hardly a legal expert, more like an outlaw, but it sounds right to me).

The article in question is linked [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm26/fm26133.pdf). The rogue excerpt can be found in the beginning of section 1.3.

Comment: @Did: But $K$ is introduced as just an arbitrary family of sets. It is not given a-priori that $f_e$ is measurable with respect to it. How can we tell in (a) that $f_e$ is measurable with respect to $K$? Rather (a) seems to say: "If $f_e$ is measuragle w.r.t. $K$, then ... (bla bla bla)"

Comment: After more careful consideration, I must withdraw my first comment. See answer.